# Contravariant method argument type

Tags: java, scala, covariance, contravariance, subtyping

wiki [Contravariant_method_argument_type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Contravariant_method_argument_type) says overriding method has the subtyping rule as function type, but no language except one support contravariant argument type. I also not able to come up with any idea of benefit to use that.

example:

```
class AnimalShelter {
    Animal getAnimalForAdoption() {      ...        }         
    void putAnimal(Animal animal) {      ...        }   
}

class CatShelter extends AnimalShelter {
    ＠Overriding        
    Cat getAnimalForAdoption() {  return new Cat();    }        
    ＠Overriding                    
    void putAnimal(Object animal) {      …        }     
}
```

My question is:

1. Is contravariant argument type of overriding method any of good use? if yes, where it is?
2. Is method a function? Why Scala has different rule for function type and overriding method type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is contravariant argument type of overriding method any of good use? if yes, where it is?

Example translated from the [Sather documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sather/docs-1.2/tutorial/type-conformance.html):

```
interface Carnivore {
  void eat(Meat food);
}

interface Herbivore {
  void eat(Plant food);
}

interface Omnivore extends Carnivore, Herbivore {
  // overrides both above eat methods,
  // since Meat and Plant are subtypes of Food
  void eat(Food food);
}
```

> Is method a function?

In Scala? No, but it can be converted to a function.

> Why Scala has different rule for function type and overriding method type?

Because overriding method types has to follow JVM's rules. It *could* be done by creating bridge methods (in the case above, adding methods `eat(Plant)` and `eat(Meat)` which just call `eat(Food)`), similarly to the way covariant return type is implemented, but it would add complexity to the language without much benefit.

Answer (score 3):

I can also add one example from [Spray](http://spray.io) toolkit, particularly [Marshaller](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/marshalling/Marshaller.scala#L24) trait. In general you can think about Marshallers as a function with converts some entity of type `T` into `HttpEntity` (for http response), but with some internal tricks, so actually it is implemented as `(T, Context) => Unit`, where `HttpEntity` is generated by this `Contenxt`. Anyway if you take a look at its declaration you'll see that it's type `T` is in contravariant position:

```
trait Marshaller[-T] {
  def apply(value: T, ctx: MarshallingContext)
}
```

Semantically you can think think about this in terms of a simple function that returns a `Unit`. And here contravariance is natural. Lets say that you have a simple hierarchy:

```
sealed trait ServerInfo {
  def data: DataTime
}

case class ServiceStatus(status: String, data: DateTime = DateTime.now) extends ServerInfo
```

With this marshallers:

```
val serverInfoMarshaller: Marshaller[ServerInfo] = ???
val serverStatusMarshaller: Marshaller[ServerStatus] = ???
```

And you have a function which return this status:

```
def response(data: ServiceStatus, marshaller: Marshaller[ServiceStatus]): Unit = ???
```

But because marshaller is contravariant, you can also use not only `serverStatusMarshaller: Marshaller[ServerStatus]`, but also `serverInfoMarshaller: Marshaller[ServerInfo]`, cause it also knows how to serialize `ServerStatus` into the correct response for the user.